# How to avoid table fitting the whole page?

Tags: tables, columns, size

I would like my table to have the size of the text in the columns, not fit the whole page as currently is in the example at the bottom. Anyone knows how to fix this?

[image]

Code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{xltabular} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}  
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter1\hangindent1em}X}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\textheight}

\begin{document}


\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} ll @{}}

\caption{xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx}
\label{tab:my-table}\\
\toprule
\textbf{xxxxxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxxxxxxx} \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}
{Table \thetable: xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxx (Continued)} \\ \addlinespace[14.4pt]
\toprule
\textbf{xxxxxxxxx} & \textbf{xxxxxxxxx} \\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% body of table
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\textbf{xxxxxxxxxxx}} \\[0.25ex]
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx & zzzz zzzz zzzz \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xx & zzzz zzzz zzzz \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx & zzzz zzzz zzzz \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx & zzzz zzzz zzzz \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxx & zzzz zzzz zzzz \\

\addlinespace 
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\textbf{xxxxxxxxxxxx}} \\[0.25ex]
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxx & zzzz zzzz zzzz \\
xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx & zzzz zzzz zzzz \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx & zzzz zzzz zzzz \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx & zzzz zzzz zzzz \\
xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxx & zzzz zzzz zzzz \\
xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx & zzzz zzzz zzzz \\

%\hline
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you are  forcing that with `\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} Lllll @{}}`  use a standard `longtable` instead
`

Comment: why are you using a table at all as every row only has one entry???

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle - is there a way to replace \textwidth with something else so that I can use xltabular? I am not familiar with long table unfortunately. Re your question, this was just an example.

Comment: xltabular is a minor extension of longtable that just adds the feature that you are asking to remove.

Comment: Does your real document -- as opposed to the test document shown above -- employ a two-column layout? If so, you should probably be thinking of using a `supertabular` environment, not an `xltabular` environment. Please advise.

Comment: Hi @Mico In my real document I am using \documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{report}. I have edited my question to include an example with 2 columns which is actually what I have.

Comment: Please clarify what your opening sentence, "I would like my table to have the size of the text in the columns", could mean. Which columns? What is "size of the text in the columns" supposed to mean?

Comment: Thanks @Mico , I have just added a new picture to my question that hopefully clarifies what I mean.